# Unable to Setup Wildcard SSL for Azure Cloud Service

Tags: asp.net, azure, ssl-certificate, azure-cloud-services, azure-sdk-.net

I need to move an azure cloud service (not an azure website) from a single domain ssl to a wildcard ssl using Windows Azure SDK 2.1 with Visual Studio 2010 ASP.NET 4.0 application.

Right now the application is using a CNAME record in dotster to map to the single ssl address to map from domain.com to myapp.cloudapp.net. It looks like A record is needed to map a wildcard ssl. I was able to create a reserved ip of the current vip ip used by the cloud service. But when i went to add the `<ReservedIP>` element to the service configuration file

```
<NetworkConfiguration>
    <AddressAssignments>
      <ReservedIPs>
       <ReservedIP name="MyReservedIP"/>
      </ReservedIPs>
    </AddressAssignments>
  </NetworkConfiguration>
```

The visual studio 2010 ide says “The element ‘ServiceDefinition’ in namespace ‘http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceDefinition' has invalid child element ‘Network Configuration’ in namespace ‘http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/'. List of possible elements expected: ‘WebRole, WorkerRole. NetworkTrafficRules’ in namespace ‘http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/'

How can I setup a wildcard ssl to the azure cloud service?

P.S. We need to stay with Azure Cloud Service and cannot use Azure Websites

Here's the entire ServiceDefinition.csdef file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceDefinition name="WindowsAzureProject1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceDefinition" schemaVersion="2013-03.2.0">
  <WebRole name=“MyWebsite vmsize="ExtraSmall">
    <Sites>
      <Site name="Web">
        <Bindings>
          <Binding name="Endpoint1" endpointName="Endpoint1" />
          <Binding name="Endpoint2" endpointName="Endpoint2" />
        </Bindings>
      </Site>
    </Sites>
    <ConfigurationSettings>
      <Setting name="AccountName" />
      <Setting name="AccountSharedKey" />
    </ConfigurationSettings>
    <Endpoints>
      <InputEndpoint name="Endpoint1" protocol="http" port="80" />
      <InputEndpoint name="Endpoint2" protocol="https" port="443" certificate=“MY-SSL" />
    </Endpoints>
    <Imports>
      <Import moduleName="Diagnostics" />
      <Import moduleName="RemoteAccess" />
      <Import moduleName="RemoteForwarder" />
    </Imports>
    <Certificates>
      <Certificate name=“MY-SSL" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" />
      <Certificate name=“ROOT”-SSL storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="CA" />
    </Certificates>
    <Startup>
      <Task commandLine="startup\disableTimeout.cmd" executionContext="elevated" />
      <!--<Task commandLine="startup\NDP40-KB2624480-x64.exe /q" executionContext="elevated" />-->
    </Startup>
  </WebRole>
    <NetworkConfiguration>
        <AddressAssignments>
            <ReservedIPs>
                <ReservedIP name="MyReservedIP"/>
            </ReservedIPs>
        </AddressAssignments>
    </NetworkConfiguration>
</ServiceDefinition>
```

Comment: Can you post the entire configuration file?

Answer (score 1):

Just to check... Could you please clarify if the block you shared is wrapped in a "ServiceConfiguration" tag as shown below :

```
<ServiceConfiguration>
 <NetworkConfiguration>
    <AddressAssignments>
      <ReservedIPs>
       <ReservedIP name="MyReservedIP"/>
      </ReservedIPs>
    </AddressAssignments>
  </NetworkConfiguration>
</ServiceConfiguration>
```

Our latest .NET Azure SDK is 2.8.1 . I'm guessing that you are hitting to this issue because you are using Windows Azure SDK 2.1 . Regarding this version, "Azure SDK for .NET 2.1 Release Notes" article in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn407359.aspx states that

Visual Studio 2010 Will Not Be Supported in Future Versions of the SDK

We are providing advance notice that the Azure SDK for .NET 2.1 will be the last release of the SDK that will support Visual Studio 2010. The next release of the SDK will add support for Visual Studio 2013 and discontinue support for Visual Studio 2010. You can continue to use Visual Studio 2010 for projects that use Azure SDK for .NET versions 2.1 and earlier.

While version 2.1 of the SDK continues to support Visual Studio 2010, Visual Studio 2012, and Visual Studio 2013 Preview, we recommend that you upgrade your Visual Studio 2010 projects to Visual Studio 2012 or Visual Studio 2013 once this SDK is released. **Upgrading your projects now will ensure that you are able to use the latest features of Azure when the next version of the SDK is released.**

I will suggest you to start using Visual Studio 2015 and our latest SDK. You can download Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition from https://www.visualstudio.com/ for free. You can download the .NET SDK for Visual Studio 2015 (or 2013) from https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/.

Comment: yes i was adding the xml in the way you suggested. for now I need to stay with this older sdk until we can migrate to a newer version of Visual Studio - so is there a way to use wildcard ssls in the older sdk? seems like people must have been using wildcard certificates for cloud services in azure back before Visual Studio 2012 was released a few years back

Comment: You had shared your CSDEF file above and CSDEf file contains the block below : <NetworkConfiguration>....</NetworkConfiguration> which is not correct. This block should be in your CSCFG file not CSDEF. Could you please double-check and let us know the result ?

Comment: i was trying to put it in the .csdef - i just tried to put it in the csdef file and it said networkconfiguration was ok but now says The element <AddressAssignments> has invalid child element of <ReservedIps> list of possible elements expected <InstanceAddress>

Comment: Now you are getting the "correct" error message. Because <ReservedIPs> was not defined in the schema when SDK was in version 2.1 .